# How to use DRACO Loader with GLTF Loader?

Tags: javascript, three.js

**Hello guys!**

Been doing some experiments with three.js, managed to get a 70mb model down to 10 MB using draco, however I am not really familiar with Draco and I haven't been able to find a good example on how to use Draco loader together with GLTF Loader, can anyone show me a good example or check my code to see which things I have to change to use it and load the compressed model? TYSM!

```html
    import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';
        import Stats from './jsm/libs/stats.module.js';
        import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
        import { GLTFLoader } from './jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

        let camera, scene, renderer, stats;
        var raycaster, mouse = { x : 0, y : 0 };
        var objects = []; 
        var selectedObject;


        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            const container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 20 );
            camera.position.set( - 1.8, 0.6, 2.7 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xa0a0a0 );
            raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();


            const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xa0a0a0,  0xa0a0a0, 2);
            scene.add(hemiLight);


                // model
                
                        const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( 'models/fbx/lowlight3_out/' );
                        loader.load( 'lowlight3.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

                            gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {

                        if ( child.isMesh ) {

                            child.castShadow = true;
                            child.receiveShadow = true;


                        }

                    } );

                    scene.add( gltf.scene );

                } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys just managed to get it working, just add to add Draco by following the three.js default example:

Add

```
import { DRACOLoader } from './jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';
```

&

```
                    const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( 'models/fbx/compressed/' );
                    const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
                    dracoLoader.setDecoderPath( './js/libs/draco/' );
                    loader.setDRACOLoader( dracoLoader );
```

For anyone having the same issue, just take a look to this example:

https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader